# Creating an empty numpy with column names and types, and adding a first row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

as title say, I want to create a empty numpy array, and adds first row,
later will come more, sure, but first step first

I try:

```
myNp= np.empty( shape=(0,8),
                 dtype=[('city', np.str_), 
                        ('country_code', np.str_), 
                        ('latitude', np.single), 
                        ('longitude', np.single), 
                        ('timezone', np.str_), 
                        ('is_active' , np.bool_),
                        ('is_underInv' , np.bool_),
                        ('is_promoted' , np.bool_)
                        ])


sampleCity=['myCity','ZA',51.51,-0.123,'Central TimeZone',True,True,True]

print(myNp)
print(sampleCity)

myNp= np.vstack((myNp, sampleCity))

print(myNp)
```

but all I got is invalid type promotion

Comment: `samplecity` has to be an array with matching `dtype`.  But in the bigger picture, don't build an array (any shape or dtype) by `vstack` repeatedly.

Comment: Build your structured array from a list of tuples, or with element assignment as done in the answer.  If you must concatenate make sure all arrays have the matching `dtype`.  Don't assume that `np.vstack` will do that for you.  And do pay attention to the `dtype` corrections in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You get a structured or record array when you mix data types (string, floats, and bools).
You had the dtype correct, but the shape should be a tuple like this: `shape=(nrows,)`.
Also, you need to allocate a string size when you create an empty array.
See modified code below. It shows how add data to one row. You can also add data "column-wise" referencing the field name (`myNp['city'] = array_of_city_names`)

```
dt = dtype=[('city',  'S20'), 
            ('country_code', 'S20'), 
            ('latitude', np.single), 
            ('longitude', np.single), 
            ('timezone',  'S20'), 
            ('is_active' , np.bool_),
            ('is_underInv' , np.bool_),
            ('is_promoted' , np.bool_)
            ]

myNp = np.empty( shape=(8,), dtype=dt)

sampleCity = np.array([('myCity','ZA',51.51,-0.123,
                        'Central TimeZone',True,True,True)], 
                         dtype=dt)

print(sampleCity)
myNp[0] = sampleCity    
print(myNp[0])
```

Comment: I think error is in the list he's trying to `vstack`.  Its dtype does not match.

Comment: I don't use `vstack`, so can't comment. Using  `np.str_` with `np.empty()` results in a zero length string for `'city', 'country_code', and 'timezone'`. Allocating them may be enough to solve the problem. Also, I just noticed a cut-n-paste error in my code (I will fix it).